# How to add new column to select statement with JSqlParser

Tags: java, jsqlparser

This is my sql statement.

```
String sql = "select mydate from mytable";
```

How can i add new columns to it dynamically with JSqlParser?

For example i want to add "mylocation" column to my sql query:

```
String sql = "select mydate, mylocation from mytable";
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting ? Please add some details to your question

Comment: i don't get any errors. i am looking for the code to do this since the documentation is lacking and i can't find anywhere how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation it should work like this:

```
Select select = (Select) CCJSqlParserUtil.parse("select mydate from mytable");
SelectUtils.addExpression(select, new Column("mylocation"));
```